# How to add a row to an ODS sheet by PHP?

Tags: php

I want a PHP script that adds some data at the end of a libreoffice sheet, under Ubuntu. What's the best (and easiest) way to do it?
Thank you very much

The biggest problem is: **how to know which is the last filled row? I have to add data at the end of the sheet.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this class

http://sourceforge.net/projects/ods-php/

Comment: Already viewed... but how to know which is the last filled row? I have to add data at the end of the sheet...